# How to get the Twitter follower count of a user on a given date, or at the time of a tweet?

Tags: twitter

I have access to Twitter API for Academic Research, and I'd like to get the follower count on a given date of a user, or at the time of a tweet.

The doc mentions that "This fields parameter enables you to select which specific user fields will deliver in each returned Tweet.", so I assumed that by adding `public_metrics` to the `users.field`, the number of followers can be seen in each returned Tweet, however, in each returned Tweet, I can only see `user_id`. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference.

Is it even possible to achieve what I want with Twitter API for Academic Research? Is there any other approach to make it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the follower count on a specific date; it will always be the count at the time you make the API call.

You may need to add `expansions` to your API call in order to receive the values you are trying to pull out.